# Find which files cause Simulink model to rebuild

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a main model (MainModel) that references to another model (ReferencedModelName) in accelerator mode.
Recently it have started to require rebuild alot of times, but I dont know what has changed.

Is there any clever way to find out which file that cause my referenced model to rebuild all the time?

```
### Checking the status of model reference SIM target for model 'ReferencedModelName' used in 'MainModel'
### Model reference SIM target (ReferencedModelName_msf.mexw64) for model ReferencedModelName is out of date because a MATLAB file used by a Stateflow block or a MATLAB Function block has changed.
### Updating model reference SIM target for model: ReferencedModelName
### Generating code into build....
```

Comment: Have you confirmed your settings in the model referencing pane of the model configuration? One of the possibilities is that the rebuild logic is set to "always".
http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/gui/model-referencing-pane.html?refresh=true

Comment: The setting is to rebuild "If any changes in known dependencies detected". My question is not how to configure the rebuild behavior, it is more like if there is any way of finding out if and which dependencies has changed